# Galleria Plugin with jQuery .load() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, galleria

I am using Galleria plugin for a website of my friend who is photographer. The plugin works fine, but here is the question. I would like to load (on click) several image galleries using .load (AJAX) from several html files where the photos and the initiating script of Galleria are located. The point is to show off several different image sets without reloading the index page. Here is the code for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--Load Galleria-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/galleria/galleria-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.sbh').load('brown.html');
            });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="content">
                <div id="gallery-handler">
                     <div class="slv">
                        <div class="sth">
                            <div class="srv">
                                <div class="sbh">
                                    <!--Loading Galleria-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><!--#gallery-handler-->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="click">Click me</p>
        </div><!--#content-->
</body>
```

As you can see, when the document.ready it loads the brown.html within div.sbh
Contents of brown.html as follows:

```
<div id="gallery">
   <a href="images/folio/11.jpg">
      <img title="" alt="" src="images/thumbs/11.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="images/folio/6.jpg">
      <img title="" alt="" src="images/thumbs/6.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="images/folio/8.jpg">
      <img title="" alt="" src="images/thumbs/8.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="images/folio/10.jpg">
      <img title="" src="images/thumbs/10.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="images/folio/16.jpg">
      <img title="" src="images/thumbs/16.jpg">
   </a>
   <a href="images/folio/13.jpg">
      <img title="" alt="" src="images/thumbs/13.jpg">
   </a>
   </div>
<script>
 // Load the classic theme
                                        Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js');

// Initialize Galleria
 $('#gallery').galleria({
 width:1000,
 height:400,
 autoplay:2500
 });
</script>
```

As you may see, brown.html has no head tags, doctype declarations etc., because all of this info (1) is not parsed by .load(), (2) is not needed as it has been indicated in index.html

Now, it works well when index.html is loaded on my localhost. As requested it shows off the photos of brown.html in div.sbh

I have the similar html file called blue.html which contains same code as brown.html but with different images. What do I need is to load blue.html content exactly as I did with brown.html when let's say I click some link on index page.

So the question is how to load contents of blue.html into div.sbh at index page without reloading the page while contents of brown.html are already loaded on document.ready? How to do multiple loads and unloads considering I will have several similar files?

Comment: I'm having trouble following you. Let’s see if I got this right: You want to load a gallery (including galleria initializer) via AJAX into a container div. Later you want to do the same again (maybe on click?) with a different gallery and append (?) it to the same container div as the first gallery? And again and again…?

Comment: Well, first have a look at http://www.bluemarlinbd.com/ please. There, you can see that click on navigation item loads the data into frame or div. The same I would like to do with this site. There will be several image sets sorted in several gallerias in seperate HTML files. So, the idea is to load this galleries without reloading whole page. The problem is here - on DOM.ready first file is well loaded, what I want to do is to unload this file and load another on click.

Comment: The page in question doesn't seem to contain any links which would trigger AJAX requests.

Comment: It doesn't yet, but, if there were some links, let's say "Hey, I am a link to Blue.html which should load in .sbh", how should I pass the commands to trigger it? Is there opposite to .load() command in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an updated version!** Find the original answer from the revisions.

I'm still not fully sure if I understand what you need, but the following is a navigation and a container for content loaded using AJAX (e.g. galleries). The files gallery1…3.html would all contain content like your brown.html does now **but remove the JS from it**.

The Javascript code underneath will attach a click event to the navigation links, and when clicked, use the `href` attribute to decide on what to load and return false to prevent the default behavior of the link (load the linked resource). We will load the theme once right after the page is loaded and initialize the gallery for the newly loaded content in the `success` callback of the `load()` method.

Then the first link is triggered when the page is loaded to show the first gallery by default. This would replace the code in you `ready` handler.

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="gallery1.html">Gallery 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery2.html">Gallery 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery3.html">Gallery 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sbh"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria/themes/twelve/galleria.twelve.min.js');
    $('#navigation a')
    .click(function(){
        $('.sbh').load(this.href, function(){
            $('#gallery').galleria({
                width:1000,
                height:400,
                autoplay:2500
            });
        });
        return false;
    })
    .first()
    .trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Let me check this, and I will come back to you soon. Thanks, man!

Comment: Seems it recognizes the command, but the script which is responsible for loading images and playing them is not initiated. Would it be right thing if we bring up the Galleria init. script into index page and leave the blue and brown htmls with links to images only?

Comment: Then it will initialize the gallery only for the initially loaded gallery (given that there is one). Do you have this online somewhere for us to have a look at? Should be pretty straight forward IMO. // Also try to be more specific: What doesn't work with the code suggested? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Here http://yerlan.sexyi.am/ I uploaded entire website, which includes three HTMLs: index, blue and brown. I made changes you advised and it loads first file, however onclick it does nothing at all. Will you check this? Thanks,

Comment: Your example seems to work so far, except that your second page throws a JS error: `Error: Fatal error: Width & Height not found.`

Comment: When I click to the first link again, it doesn't do anything, beside throwing another bunch of errors... :( Any ideas?

Comment: I've just tested it and updated my answer. Please read it again and try once more. It should work like this. You might want to remove the tracker code or check it, since it throws errors. I believe that it belongs at least in the `<body>` tag, though. Not outside the `<html>` tag anyways.

Comment: :( Doesn't work. Brown.html loads OK on page load, but when clicking on blue it doesn't load images at all, though galleria theme is loaded. When clicking on brown.html (I suppose, it's the .first() in the code) it works well and loads the contents of brown.html. I assume the code doesn't recognize trigger or smth else... Too sad... You said you tested, can you show off your code? Thanks

Comment: Yes, have a look here: http://polarblau.com/so/6839912/ (I had used the classic theme for testing, though).

Comment: Super!!! My friend, now it works! I don't know how to thank you! Thanks, pal! My friend, who is photographer, will be very happy! Thanks once again!